# Tips for discrete mathematics in Contests and a example problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, problem-solving

In the last time I did lot's of preparations for future math contests and I discovered a problem where I don't know how to start with.

Here is the problem:

> *In a spa there are 100 showers. In every shower is a faucet which controlles the water for this shower. Due to a mistake every faucet controlles the water for exactly 5 other showers as well.
>
>   Show that you can ever select 10 showers so that you don't notice the defect, when you close the remaining 90 showers.*

I already tried it with a graph, so every shower is connected to 5 other showers. Then I tested wether ther is a peculiarity. But that's where it ends.
Maybe I don't know about specific techniques for such problems? I hope that I can look at some example solutions (for this and simmilar problems;I would be very grateful if you could post links to similar problems with solutions) and discover a own way to attack such problems.
Maybe you have other advices as well.

> problem source: [German Mathmatic Olympiade 2010 for 11th graders](https://www.mathematik-olympiaden.de/aufgaben/50/1/A50131.pdf) (PDF)

Warm regards CodeCrafter1

Comment: Note that you want to find an independent set in the graph. Then there are known lower bounds depending on the number of edges of the graph

Comment: @DonThousand We start with shower 1 and remove the $5$ showers that are also affected by shower $1$'s faucet.  How do we know that none of the remaining $94$ showers has a faucet that affects shower $1$?  I don't see anything in the problem statement about symmetry.

Comment: @saulspatz True, my mistake.

Comment: This won't work, but right now I'm not seeing where this argument fails: "We pick our first shower at random, turn on the water. Then we look for a dry one, and turn on the water there again,..."; For every shower we turn on, we lose at most 5 further showers, so we can always find $\lfloor 100/6\rfloor = 16$ showers that are not affecting each other

Comment: @Sudix It's the same problem I pointed out with Don Thousand's comment.  You turn on faucet $1$, and showers $2,3,4,5,6$ start running, so you turn on shower $7$, and shower $1$ stops running.

Comment: @saulspatz But then wouldn't shower 1 be connected to $|\{2,3,4,5,6,7\}|= 6$ other showers, and not exactly 5 other showers... oh, wait, you're saying the graph is directed?

Comment: @Sudix That not what it says.  It says that each faucet controls the operation of five showers besides its own.  It does not say that these are the same faucets that control its operation.  It may be that your interpretation is what's intended, because a literal interpretation seems to make it a very hard problem.  From the poor, ragged remnants of my German though, it seems to me that the OP's translation of the original question is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a directed graph in which every vertex has out-degree $5$; if we forget the orientation of the edges, then the average degree in the graph is $10$. (Though it's possible for some vertices to have higher degree; maybe every single shower toggles shower #1.)

There's a fairly standard greedy algorithm here, but it's not the obvious greedy algorithm (which doesn't work) so that trips people up.

The key is this: in any set $S$ of showers, there will be a shower $x \in S$ which interacts with (toggles, or is toggled by) at most $10$ showers in $S$. This is just because the subgraph induced by $S$ has $|S|$ vertices and at most $5|S|$ edges (maybe fewer, if a shower in the set $S$ toggles showers outside that set) so the average degree is $10$ or less.

We can start by letting $S$ be the set of all showers, and let $x_1$ be this shower. Then, remove both $x_1$, and all the showers it interacts with, from $S$. We are left with at least $100-11 = 89$ showers.

Let $x_2$ be the shower which interacts with at most $10$ showers in the new $S$. Again, remove both $x_2$ and the showers it interacts with from $S$, and repeat.

We lose $11$ showers at each step, so after $9$ steps we'll still have at least $100-9 \cdot 11 = 1$ shower left to pick.

(The general result of this argument is that a graph with $n$ vertices and average degree $d$ has an independent set of size $\lceil \frac{n}{d+1}\rceil$, which is a restatement of Turán's theorem.)

Comment: Thak you verry much for your detailed and helpfull explanation. And as always if you read a genius solution the problem doesn't look that difficult any more.